# Isn't heating insulator enough for sufficient electrons to escape valence band and conduct electricity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, electricity, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Diamond has about **5.5eV** of energy gap, So If I heat diamond it will get atleast **1J** energy which is enough to excite about **10^18** electrons, But Diamond still not conduct electricity, Why?

Comment: The key parameter here is the temperature that you heat the material to. This will determine the equilibrium intrinsic carrier concentration. Note that this is a dynamic equilibrium between generation and recombination of carriers - exciting a bunch of carriers that then quickly recombine does not change the equilibrium concentration.

Answer (score 0):

When you heat a solid to a temperature $T$ the random thermal energy available to the electrons in the valence band is of order $kT$. where $k$ is [Boltzmann's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant). To get the $5.5~\textrm{eV}$ necessary for the electrons to jump into the conduction band you would have to heat the diamond to about $64000~\textrm{K}$, though obviously the diamond would vaporise long before this temperature was reached.